# Flash Games Downloader

Tags: download, flash

Im looking for a program to download flash games so I can run them on my desktop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [How To Download and Play Flash Games Offline](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/download-play-flash-games-offline/).